# Is "strategization" a word, or is there something more correct/appropriate?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

Is *strategization* a word? As in:

> We noticed flaws in their accounting department so the project will
>   include a QuickBooks strategization.

[EDIT] As @tchrist points out, this isn't the best example, so here's a better one:

> Strategization and conceptualization with teams of designers,
>   developers, and animators

I've searched and found it seems like it *should* be by [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/consulting/comments/7w88o9/is_this_a_word_strategization/dtybeiv/), unless they are being sarcastic:

> Yeah, the word strategization is a noun form of a verb that already
>   came from a noun. The next step would be strategizationize, which I
>   would be opposed to in any context if it weren’t for the fact that we
>   could then progress to strategizationizationery.

What rationale would be used to determine if this is a word, if it's not specifically in any dictionary? If not a word, what would be more correct? And should I avoid it in a résumé, even though it's the closest thing to the meaning I want, and (possibly) a real word? If spell check and/or HR doesn't like it, and that might doink a job opportunity.

Comment: I don't understand what a Quickbooks strategization would mean that a Quickbooks strategy would not.

Comment: For some readers, words like *strategization and conceptualization* will be an instant turn-off because of how ponderous those are; they'll wonder why you couldn't just say that you explored strategies and concepts. Yet for others more prone to bureaucratizationalizing their prose, those selfsame words will favorably mark you as part of their "in-group". These are all productive affixes: that means you get to use them to mint new words however you please no matter what "the dictionary" says. Just don't expect them to please all who read them.

Comment: Further true points. Glad I came here to ask.

Comment: *Strategizing* and *conceptualizing* are okay.  The *-tion* versions are a bridge too far.

Comment: What about *planning*? I'm unaware of any specific difference, other than the implications of serious bizniz.

Answer (score -2):

You've gone from noun ("strategy") to verb ("strategizing"--making a *strategy*) back to noun ("strategization"--the result of *strategizing*--i.e. the result of *making a strategy*--i.e. a ***strategy!***)

The correct phrasing on the first example would be:

> "We noticed flaws in their accounting department so the project will include a QuickBooks **strategy**."

Using QuickBooks is a great strategy for whipping an accounting dept into shape!

In the second example, I think the verb form is fine:

> *Job responsibilities include:*
>
> - Strategizating and conceptualizating with teams of designers, developers, and animators

Comment: Has *strategizating* been cromulentizated?

Comment: I think the verb form is awful. Why do you think it fine? Would you write something like that rather than "Determining strategy and defining concepts (or whatever this is supposed to mean)… And if you must form verbs of this sort, why the "at"? But this is an English language site, so we should call a spade a spade.

Comment: "strategization" is the process of strategizing not the result.